# How to set AnonymousAuthenticationToken in SecurityContext (Spring Boot 1.5.1)

Tags: security, web

I am working on a microservice to enable validation of an anonymous JWT token.
After validating the jwt token for different attributes (such as issuer, expiration time etc.) I need to set AnonymousAuthenticationToken in SecurityContext by executing -

SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
.setAuthentication(anonymousAuthenticationToken);

This line will be inside my filter class that is extending org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.

The constructor of AnonymousAuthenticationToken  takes these three arguments:-

String key,Object principal,Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities

I understand the principal is issuer of the token. How do I get values of key and authorities?
Also, is it okay to extend OncePerRequestFilter or should I extend some other filter?

Answer (score 0):

AnonymousAuthenticationToken class code says:

```
/**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param key         to identify if this object made by an authorised client
     * @param principal   the principal (typically a <code>UserDetails</code>)
     * @param authorities the authorities granted to the principal
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if a <code>null</code> was passed
     */
    public AnonymousAuthenticationToken(String key, Object principal,
                                        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this(extractKeyHash(key), principal, authorities);
    }
```

For every User, some roles will be defined. You can generate authorities from those roles:

```
private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> translate(List<Roles> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(roles)){
            for (Roles role : roles) {
                String name = "ROLE_"+role.getRoleId().toUpperCase();
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(name));
            }
        }
        return authorities;
    }
```

"key" is basically the client secret key defined for your application to get recognized