# What is the key in Spring Security AnonymousAuthenticationToken for?

Tags: spring-security

After a successful logout without a followup redirect I have an empty `SecurityContext` which I wanna populate with the standard Spring Security [AnonymousAuthenticationToken](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/AnonymousAuthenticationToken.html).

The constructor asks for a key which gets hashed, and the documentation says that this key is required `to identify if this object made by an authorised client`.

- Can anybody tell what this exactly means?
- Where does this key play a role in the security behavior of the application?
- Can I provide any `String` as key or has it to be a specific one to get the standard anonymous token?

Many thanks for any information

Comment: the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62975450/how-to-set-anonymousauthenticationtoken-in-securitycontext-spring-boot-1-5-1) can give you answer

Comment: Thanks @AndreiLisa, but the answer `"key" is basically the client secret key defined for your application to get recognized` throws just another question: what is the client secret key? So now we have 4 open questions^^?

Comment: A client secret is a secret known only to the `OAuth` application and the authorization server. It is generated by the authorization server during the process of application registration. A client has to provide its client secret to authenticate itself to the authorization server and to be able to get a token.

Comment: So I can choose any random string for this purpose and since it's an anonymous authorization token it will serve no further purpose? But whats the point in that to ask for the key in the first place?

Comment: I think you should read [it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html) first of all and then you will be able to create a simple pet project to have more understand on it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll read it in the evening and hopefully get some grasp out of it. I'm not using OAuth but if the mechanisms regarding anonymous tokens are the same the information might help anyway. Many thanks for your help.